# HTTP POST with body with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, http-post, form-data

My Spring Boot backend needs to integrate with the [Moloni](https://www.moloni.com) API (a cloud software for invoicing).

My problem is in sending data in the body of the HTTP POST. JSON or XML won't work. It needs to be in **form-data**. For a simple parameter, it would be something like:

```
"company_id", "xxxx"
```

But for an array, it would be:

```
"products[0][product_id]", "xxxx"
"products[0][name]", "yyyy"
"products[1][product_id]", "aaaaa"
"products[1][name]", "bbbbb"
```

An object inside an array can itself have an array inside, etc.

My question is: is there a way to convert a POJO into this structure?
What's the best approach?

Comment: Hello @BranislavLazic, unfortunately JSON or XML won't work for this API. It must be form-data.